# Django CMS simple placeholders outside of cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have a fully developed Django app and decided to add DjangoCMS to give a content developers a quick way to prototype landing pages etc. It now lives under myurl.com/cms and works quite well. The guys can create new pages, choose a template and add plugins there.

When i saw the placeholder template tag I immediately thought about placing it all over the project, outside the cms, everywhere I want the product team to be able to quickly add and change content. I don't want them to create a new page for this from the cms because maybe the site has complex functionality which is only used once in this context (i.e. the search page).

So basically I expect to have static placeholders that I can place in the html part of the page using the cms plugins template tags.

I already found [Placeholders outside the CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/placeholders.html) in the DjangoCMS docs.
But for this to work I have to grab the related placeholder object for every view that renders a page, which would increase the amount of work to "quickly add a placeholder for this text" considerably.

Is there an easy way to do this? I kind of expect to not be the first to have that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's three types of placeholders:

Page placeholders - Declared using `{% placeholder %}`. These can        only be used inside a cms page.

Static placeholders - Declared using `{% static_placeholder %}`. Not bound to pages or objects.

App placeholder - Declared in your models.py using PlaceholderField    and rendered in template using `{% render_placeholder %}`

The rule of thumb is, if you're rendering a cms page, use a page placeholder, otherwise depending on your use-case use a static placeholder.